# How to get past X-Frame-Options in javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed

I am trying to embed the youtube live chat for youtube live events. I am having trouble when getting past the X-Frame-Options set to SAMEORIGIN. I don't have access to install php or anything on our server as it is pbs provided. I have seen solutions with pho. So is there anyway to do this with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

No, absolutely not.

You can't use client side code to override security instructions given to the client by another site.

---

YouTube provide embed code for their videos, just use that (it might be possible for it to be disabled for some videos in which case this might not be an option).

Comment: The only problem is I can't embed the live chat that goes with it. My work days that they want it embeded. If I could get a server that had php is there a way to do it?

Comment: You could theoretically proxy everything, but I expect they use websockets to handle the chat side of things so it would be distinctly non-trivial.